# Prove an integral inequality: $ \left(\int|f|^2dx\right)^2\le 4\left(\int|xf(x)|^2dx\right)\left(\int|f'|^2dx\right) $

Tags: real-analysis, integral-inequality

If $f$ is real-valued and continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, prove that
$$
 \left(\int|f|^2dx\right)^2\le 4\left(\int|xf(x)|^2dx\right)\left(\int|f'|^2dx\right)
$$

Attempt: I tried the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality as well as the Plancherel theorem, but none of them seems to work.

Comment: What if $f\equiv 1?$

Comment: We need some other hypotheses on $f$. For instance, sufficient conditions to ensure $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} xf(x)^2 = 0$. In which case 

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty xff' \ dx = \left[\frac 12  xf^2 \right]_{-\infty}^\infty - \int \frac 12 f^2 \ dx = - \frac 12 \int f^2 dx$$ and we can apply C-S.

Comment: I thought it is implied in the inequality that $f$, $xf(x)$ and $f'$ are all in $L^2$.

Comment: Usually I think we are more explicit. But assuming everything is $L^2$, then my hint gives the answer.

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks Simon.

Comment: Let me write that as an answer so you can accept it and the question is marked as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For well behaved $f$ (and usually suppressing limits of integration):

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty xff' \ dx = \left[\frac 12  xf^2 \right]_{-\infty}^\infty - \int \frac 12 f^2 \ dx = - \frac 12 \int f^2 dx$$

Now applying Cauchy-Schwarz,

$$\left( \int |f|^2 \ dx \right)^2 = 4 \left( \int xff' \ dx \right)^2 \leq 4 \left( \int |xf|^2 \ dx \right) \left( \int |f'|^2 \ dx \right)$$